# Truncate a String from a file name

Tags: java, string

I have previously written a code where I have added a time stamp to a file once it has been save in a directory.
Now I wanna to be able to truncate the time stamp from the file which comes after the extension .txt
note that my time stamp format is:_yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: If you show your code snippet. It will be better.

Comment: when you get the answer you are looking for click the check mark next to that answer to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the date after your extension in the form `_yyyy-mm-dd` just can use

```
String strippedFileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - 11);
```

or a bit nicer

```
String dateFormatString = "_yyyy-mm-dd";
String strippedFileName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.length() - dateFormatString.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
String trimmed = filename.replaceAll(".{11}$", "");
```